# Question about embedding a UIImage in a UIWebview; how do you get rid of the border?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

Here is the code I am using:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *HTMLData = @"<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=320\"/> <img src=\"image.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\">";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

There is a white border surrounding the image in the web view. Is there any way to just have the image take up the screen?

Edit: Added screenshot

[image: The white border around the image is the problem]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can u post a screenshot of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a body tag that has its CSS margin property set to 0px. The generated HTML should look like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320"/>
<body style="margin:0px;">
...img tag goes here...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried adding border="0"

Change: `<img src=\"image.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\">`

To: `<img src=\"image.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"320\" height=\"480\ border=\"0\">`

Comment: Yes, the problem is unfortunately still persisting.

Comment: Seems like some extra margin / padding in there. Let add `body` tag with `style="margin:0;padding:0"`